# How to copy a font data block(ID) from active to selected strips?

Tags: python, scripting, video-sequence-editor, data-blocks

I need to copy/link the font chosen in the active strip in the VSE to every text strip in the selection. So I need the get the current font ID of the active strip and apply that ID to all strips in the selection.

```
import bpy
current_scene = bpy.context.scene
active = current_scene.sequence_editor.active_strip
for strip in bpy.context.selected_sequences:
    if strip.type == active.type == "TEXT":
        strip.font = active.font
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was so simple I can't believe it:

```
strip.font = active.font
```